# (SVM) Difference between linear kernel and polynomial kernel of degree 1?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, libsvm

I am new to machine learning. Could anyone tell me the difference between linear kernel vs. polynomial kernel of degree 1 wrt SVM (if there is any difference)?

The reason I asked, I am getting different accuracy for both on the spam dataset from UCI.

Answer (score 2):

**Depending on your SVM implementation**, there may be a difference.
Compared to the linear kernel, the [polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel) has an additional parameter $c$ (and $d$ of course):

$K(x,y) = (x^\mathsf{T} y + c)^{d}$

However, if $c=0$ (and $d=1$), then:

(linear) $K(x,y) = x^\mathsf{T} y \equiv K(x,y) = (x^\mathsf{T} y + c)^{d}$ (polynomial)

Nonetheless, some SVM implementations may opt-out of calculating $c$ and assume homogeneity in order to reduce the number of hyper-parameters. So, it depends on how your SVM is implemented.

For example [sklearn's polynomial kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.polynomial_kernel.html) assumes by default $c=1$ if you do not specify the parameter, which would make it not exactly the same as a linear kernel.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a difference, as the [Polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel) has an additional parameter. If you're including that as a hyper-parameter, it could explain the difference.

Otherwise, if it is fixed to 0, then they should be the same. How big a difference in accuracy are you talking? If it's fairly minor it could be due to numerical stability issues.

Comment: What is that additional parameter ?

Comment: To me, a linear kernel would mean a separating hyper plane and that doesn't necessarily go through the origin.  I wonder if this isn't something with the software.  I know that Python likes to use regularization by default in some of it's ML software (e.g. logistic regression).   That is a possible source of the difference.